# Why does Remote scripting on asp classic works with IP, but not DNS name

Tags: asp-classic

I'm working on an old legacy app written in asp classic. It works with Remote scripting (rs.htm) to call asp methods from local webpages.

it works like this :

```
o = new Object();
o.execute.myFunction = Function('', '', '', 'return MSRS.invokeMethod...');
lret = o.execute.myFunction('', '', '')
```

This part works everytime when testing on a computer from the same domain, even when the website url is a dns address or an ip address.

But when I call the website from a different domain, the website is resolved, everything is displayed correctly, but the remote scripting starts to fail when it is called(it fails systematically on the line o.execute.myFunction()).

Do you know where the problem can be? Could it be the dns? Even if it is resolving from the URL?

I know this problem is outdated, but if someone has the answer, i'll be very happy!

Comment: Get any errors in the browser console or server requests that fail in the network tab?

Comment: I didn't get any error on the console. I tried to get the return value of the execution, but it just returned "-1". I didn't check the network tab.

Comment: No, it's likely a security issue check it's not being block due to XSS policies.

Comment: If the remote domain requires pre-authentication, then it could be Kerberos, and lack of proper SPN registration of the remote system in your current domain.  Using an IP address avoids Kerberos, and falls back to other authentication schemes (eg, NTLM).  Otherwise, try adding the remote domain into Internet Explorer's "Trusted sites" or "Local intranet" sites list, to avoid having it classified as an "Internet" (or "Restricted site") with all its security constraints.